# got source connection error on xcode7

Tags: swift, xcode7, info.plist

I added "AppTransport Security Setting" as dictionary and "Allow Arbitrary Loads" as boolean to YES on info.plist. However am still getting error that says below. Does anyone know solutions for this problem?

```
     NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.}
```

Comment: So what should I change?

Comment: It seems apple has security policy to not allow unsecured connection.

Comment: are there any solutions for it?

Comment: The best possible solution is to use a SSL server.

Comment: I just tried same recently by setting "Allow Arbitrary Loads" as "YES" and it is working though.

Comment: I tried the one right above but didnt work.. dont know how to fix this except the way using SSL server

Comment: did you mention your domain in NSExceptionDomains?

Comment: not yet cuz I dont know what domain i should put here. This file is commited by my friend. Do you know the way i check which domain?

Comment: Have a look at your code for any APIs. They may be pointing at some unsecured domain.